# How to save all the variables in the current python session?

Tags: python, save

I want to save all the variables in my current python environment. It seems one option is to use the 'pickle' module. However, I don't want to do this for 2 reasons:

1. I have to call `pickle.dump()` for each variable
2. When I want to retrieve the variables, I must remember the order in which I saved the variables, and then do a `pickle.load()` to retrieve each variable.

I am looking for some command which would save the entire session, so that when I load this saved session, all my variables are restored. Is this possible?

Edit: I guess I don't mind calling `pickle.dump()` for each variable that I would like to save, but remembering the exact order in which the variables were saved seems like a big restriction. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you use [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html), you do not have to remember the order in which the objects are pickled, since `shelve` gives you a dictionary-like object:

To shelve your work:

```
import shelve

T='Hiya'
val=[1,2,3]

filename='/tmp/shelve.out'
my_shelf = shelve.open(filename,'n') # 'n' for new

for key in dir():
    try:
        my_shelf[key] = globals()[key]
    except TypeError:
        #
        # __builtins__, my_shelf, and imported modules can not be shelved.
        #
        print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(key))
my_shelf.close()
```

To restore:

```
my_shelf = shelve.open(filename)
for key in my_shelf:
    globals()[key]=my_shelf[key]
my_shelf.close()

print(T)
# Hiya
print(val)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. BTW, I find this sentence in your post super funny: "To shelve your work" :)

Comment: And here I thought "pickles" were funny! :)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inherently_funny_word

Comment: is it possible to abstract the details of saving the variables in a separate function? For example example, when you loop through the names in the current local name space, you can pass that as a argument but then how do you pass the globals? Do you also have to pass the globals? as in `save(dir(),globals())` and then run your code above? Also is it possible to just call a function that abstract of restore?

Comment: I know this answer is very old byt when I do this I have the following error:
`PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in function raw_input>: it's not the same object as __builtin__.raw_input`
I just have 2 variables declared in my workspace. Any ideas on how to solve this? Has some better way to save the current session come out after this answer?

Comment: I have the same problem regarding the usage of shelve as described above. PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'numpy.int32'>: it's not the same object as numpy.int32

Comment: It looks like some builtin functions and packages won't be able to be shelved so just use `except:` instead of `except TypeError:`. This will shelve user defined variables and most objects (pandas data frames shelved fine for me)

Comment: Unbelievable that there is still no solution to this after 9 years.  The above code throws errors now, and the Save As function in Spyder simply doesn't create a file, and gives no error.  I am trying so hard to give Python a fair shake in an evaluation for my organization, but after 2 weeks I can't recommend it over R/RStudio.  I'd love to be proved wrong!

Comment: I'm getting "AttributeError: module 'shelve' has no attribute 'open'". I haven't yet worked out how to implement the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102646/module-object-has-no-attribute-open-in-shelve

Comment: Curious how would I restore the shelved variables into a different object?

Comment: can I save class objects with this tool as well? For example, if I type restore everything and type `vars(my_class)`, it gives me all the variables and functions in `my_class` just like how Spyder does.

Comment: I use `joblib`. Nothing else works for all my objects.

Answer (score 90):

Having sat here and failed to save the `globals()` as a dictionary, I discovered you can pickle a session using the dill library.

This can be done by using:

```
import dill                            #pip install dill --user
filename = 'globalsave.pkl'
dill.dump_session(filename)

# and to load the session again:
dill.load_session(filename)
```

Comment: I don't think dill saves all the variables, for example if you run dill.dump_session() in a function variables which are local to that function aren't saved.

Comment: Thats just a scope issue, I guess you could just append all your locals() to globals() if you must?

Comment: I got "TypeError: can't pickle Socket objects"

Comment: I get the following type error when dumping the session:

`TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__`

Comment: I tried this and found it can't save named arrays though this might be a pickle limitation.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'` there seems to be no support for namespace (folder only) modules perhaps? As these have `mod.__file__ is None`

Comment: I cannot find a way to make dill save also local variables and not only globals

Answer (score 13):

One very easy way that might satisfy your needs. For me, it did pretty well:

Simply, click on this icon on the Variable Explorer (right side of Spider):

[image: Saving all the variables in *.spydata format]

[image: Loading all the variables or pics etc.]

Comment: I saved all variables in .spydata format yesterday and I tried to import data today. No variable gets imported :(

Comment: This was working for me but now that I have more data it, rather than making a Spydata file, now makes a pickle file with zero contents as well as hundreds of npy files. How do I open these please?

Comment: commenting in 2023, I can no longer import spyder data files into spyder for whatever reason

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way saving the Spyder workspace variables using the spyderlib functions

```
#%%  Load data from .spydata file
from spyderlib.utils.iofuncs import load_dictionary

globals().update(load_dictionary(fpath)[0])
data = load_dictionary(fpath)



#%% Save data to .spydata file
from spyderlib.utils.iofuncs import save_dictionary
def variablesfilter(d):
    from spyderlib.widgets.dicteditorutils import globalsfilter
    from spyderlib.plugins.variableexplorer import VariableExplorer
    from spyderlib.baseconfig import get_conf_path, get_supported_types

    data = globals()
    settings = VariableExplorer.get_settings()

    get_supported_types()
    data = globalsfilter(data,                   
                         check_all=True,
                         filters=tuple(get_supported_types()['picklable']),
                         exclude_private=settings['exclude_private'],
                         exclude_uppercase=settings['exclude_uppercase'],
                         exclude_capitalized=settings['exclude_capitalized'],
                         exclude_unsupported=settings['exclude_unsupported'],
                         excluded_names=settings['excluded_names']+['settings','In'])
    return data

def saveglobals(filename):
    data = globalsfiltered()
    save_dictionary(data,filename)


#%%

savepath = 'test.spydata'

saveglobals(savepath)
```

Let me know if it works for you.
David B-H

Comment: "NameError: name 'fpath' is not defined": did I forget something?

Comment: That's a good idea. I was thinking about borrowing from spyder's workspace for the same thing. But didn't figure out how. However, I didn't quite understand your code. Could you please tell, does this work exactly like Spyder that it automatically catches all the varibles, or I have to specify the variables I want to use?

Comment: @DavidBH the spyderlib does not exist yet I can run spyder

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is to hibernate your process. This was [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134771/hibernate-a-process-in-linux) already. The conclusion is that there are several hard-to-solve problems exist while trying to do so. For example with restoring open file descriptors.

It is better to think about serialization/deserialization subsystem for your program. It is not trivial in many cases, but is far better solution in long-time perspective.

Although if I've exaggerated the problem. You can try to pickle your global variables *dict*. Use [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) to access the dictionary. Since it is varname-indexed you haven't to bother about the order.

Comment: Nopes. I am not trying to hibernate the process. I have an interactive python shell on which I run several scripts and commands. I want to save the output (variables) of some of these commands, so that in future whenever I need access to the output, I can just fire up a python shell and load all these variables.

Comment: So, pickle the dictionary var_name -> var_value

Answer (score 2):

If you want the accepted answer abstracted to function you can use:

```
    import shelve

    def save_workspace(filename, names_of_spaces_to_save, dict_of_values_to_save):
    '''
        filename = location to save workspace.
        names_of_spaces_to_save = use dir() from parent to save all variables in previous scope.
            -dir() = return the list of names in the current local scope
        dict_of_values_to_save = use globals() or locals() to save all variables.
            -globals() = Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table.
            This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method,
            this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).
            -locals() = Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table.
            Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.

        Example of globals and dir():
            >>> x = 3 #note variable value and name bellow
            >>> globals()
            {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'x': 3, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
            >>> dir()
            ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'x']
    '''
    print 'save_workspace'
    print 'C_hat_bests' in names_of_spaces_to_save
    print dict_of_values_to_save
    my_shelf = shelve.open(filename,'n') # 'n' for new
    for key in names_of_spaces_to_save:
        try:
            my_shelf[key] = dict_of_values_to_save[key]
        except TypeError:
            #
            # __builtins__, my_shelf, and imported modules can not be shelved.
            #
            #print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(key))
            pass
    my_shelf.close()

    def load_workspace(filename, parent_globals):
        '''
            filename = location to load workspace.
            parent_globals use globals() to load the workspace saved in filename to current scope.
        '''
        my_shelf = shelve.open(filename)
        for key in my_shelf:
            parent_globals[key]=my_shelf[key]
        my_shelf.close()

an example script of using this:
import my_pkg as mp

x = 3

mp.save_workspace('a', dir(), globals())
```

to get/load the workspace:

```
import my_pkg as mp

x=1

mp.load_workspace('a', globals())

print x #print 3 for me
```

it worked when I ran it. I will admit I don't understand `dir()` and `globals()` 100% so I am not sure if there might be some weird caveat, but so far it seems to work. Comments are welcome :)

---

after some more research if you call `save_workspace` as I suggested with globals and `save_workspace` is within a function it won't work as expected if you want to save the veriables in a local scope. For that use `locals()`. This happens because globals takes the globals from the module where the function is defined, not from where it is called would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a text file or a CVS file. People use Spyder for example to save variables but it has a known issue: for specific data types it fails to import down in the road.