# Shelve Code gives KeyError

Tags: python, shelve

I wanted to use the following code from here:
[How can I save all the variables in the current python session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-can-i-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session)

```
import shelve

T='Hiya'
val=[1,2,3]

filename='/tmp/shelve.out'
my_shelf = shelve.open(filename,'n') # 'n' for new

for key in dir():
    try:
        my_shelf[key] = globals()[key]
    except TypeError:
        #
        # __builtins__, my_shelf, and imported modules can not be shelved.
        #
        print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(key))
my_shelf.close()
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bingo.py", line 204, in <module>
    menu()
  File "./bingo.py", line 67, in menu
    my_shelf[key] = globals()[key]
KeyError: 'filename'
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: obviously `globals()` and `dir()` are not the same thing, why do you loop over one and index the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your traceback, it appears you are trying to run that code from inside a function.

But [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) looks up names in the *current local scope*. So if `filename` is defined inside the function, it will be in [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) rather than [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals).

You probably want something more like this:

```
import shelve

T = 'Hiya'
val = [1, 2, 3]

def save_variables(globals_=None):
    if globals_ is None:
        globals_ = globals()
    filename = '/tmp/shelve.out'
    my_shelf = shelve.open(filename, 'n')
    for key, value in globals_.items():
        if not key.startswith('__'):
            try:
                my_shelf[key] = value
            except Exception:
                print('ERROR shelving: "%s"' % key)
            else:
                print('shelved: "%s"' % key)
    my_shelf.close()

save_variables()
```

Note that when `globals()` is called from *within* the function, it returns the variables from the module where the function is *defined*, not from where it's *called*.

So if the `save_variables` function is imported, and you want the variables from the *current* module, then do:

```
save_variables(globals())
```