# How to access Aʟʟ global variables in a function?

Tags: python, global-variables, shelve

I'm trying to mimic the `matlab` load and save functions.   I'm following this thread: [Shelve Code gives KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857768/shelve-code-gives-keyerror)

It is smart. However, if I write that code in a separate module, and try to import that module and invoke that function, then it can't access the global variables.

Specifically, I write a `happy.py` and have the functions inside:

```
def save(filename='tmp', globals_=None):
    if globals_ is None:
        globals_ = globals()
        
    globals()
    import shelve
    my_shelf = shelve.open(filename, 'n')
    for key, value in globals_.items():
        if not key.startswith('__'):
            try:
                my_shelf[key] = value
            except Exception:
                print('ERROR shelving: "%s"' % key)
            else:
                print('shelved: "%s"' % key)
    my_shelf.close()

def load(filename='tmp', globals_=None):
    import shelve
    my_shelf = shelve.open(filename)
    for key in my_shelf:
        globals()[key] = my_shelf[key]
    my_shelf.close()
```

and when I try

```
a = 1
b = 2
happy.save()
```

It would not give save `a` and `b`.

Is this because `global()` would not give the objects outside the module? How can I do what I want to do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inspect` to look at the stack.  This silly (poorly named function) that I've defined seems to do an OK job of picking up the global variables from the calling namespace although I haven't tested it extensively.  I am also unsure about whether it will work with different python implementations.  (I mention this because the `inspect.currentframe` function is definitely implementation dependent).  It seems to work OK with Cpython for what it's worth.

```
import inspect
def save(globals=None):
    if globals is None:
        frames = inspect.stack()
        caller_frame = frames[-1][0]
        globals = dict((k,v) for (k,v) in caller_frame.f_globals.items() if not k.startswith('__'))
    return globals


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 1
    b = 2
    print save()
```

Comment: This seems to reliably "save" the caller's globals -- But I don't think I know how to reliably "load" the caller's globals.  The best I could do is return a dict from "load" and force the user to `globals().update(load())` which still isn't *too* bad ...

Answer (score 1):

The following will work as a separate module:

```
import shelve
import sys
import types

EXCLUDED_TYPES = (types.ModuleType,)  # Everything can't be shelved.

def save(filename='tmp', globals_=None):
    if globals_ is None:
        globals_ = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # Caller's globals.

    with shelve.open(filename, 'n') as my_shelf:
        for key, value in globals_.items():
            if not (key.startswith('__') or isinstance(value, EXCLUDED_TYPES)):
                try:
                    my_shelf[key] = value
                except Exception as e:
                    print('ERROR shelving: "%s"' % key, 'Exception:', e)
                else:
                    print('shelved: "%s"' % key)

def load(filename='tmp', globals_=None):
    if globals_ is None:
        globals_ = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # Caller's globals.

    with shelve.open(filename) as my_shelf:
        for key in my_shelf:
            globals_[key]=my_shelf[key]
            print('unshelved: "%s"' % key)
```

Generally speaking, I don't think it's a good idea for a function to create global variables like this. Also note that `load()` might silently change existing values in the caller's namespace.

You can't easily save *all* global namespaces, since there's one associated with every module loaded, in addition to `__main__`'s. If you really want to do that, it might be possible to do so by iterating through the contents of `sys.modules`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a problem with this code when it is pasted into an console:

```
>>> def save(filename='tmp',globals_=None):
...     import shelve
...     globals_ = globals_ or globals()
...     my_shelf=  shelve.open(filename, 'n')
...     for key, value in globals_.items():
...         if not key.startswith('__'):
...             try:
...                 my_shelf[key] = value
...             except Exception:
...                 print('ERROR shelving: "%s"' % key)
...             else:
...                 print('shelved: "%s"' % key)
...     my_shelf.close()
... 
>>> def load(filename='tmp',globals_=None):
...     import shelve
...     my_shelf = shelve.open(filename)
...     for key in my_shelf:
...         globals()[key]=my_shelf[key]
...     my_shelf.close()
... 
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> save()
shelved: "load"
shelved: "a"
shelved: "b"
shelved: "save"
```

And then:

```
>>> def save(filename='tmp',globals_=None):
...     import shelve
...     globals_ = globals_ or globals()
...     my_shelf=  shelve.open(filename, 'n')
...     for key, value in globals_.items():
...         if not key.startswith('__'):
...             try:
...                 my_shelf[key] = value
...             except Exception:
...                 print('ERROR shelving: "%s"' % key)
...             else:
...                 print('shelved: "%s"' % key)
...     my_shelf.close()
... 
>>> def load(filename='tmp',globals_=None):
...     import shelve
...     my_shelf = shelve.open(filename)
...     for key in my_shelf:
...         globals()[key]=my_shelf[key]
...     my_shelf.close()
... 
>>> load()
>>> a, b
(1, 2)
```

But it is a bit odd when you use it as a module:

```
>>> from happy import *
>>> a, b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> load()
>>> a, b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> happy.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'happy' is not defined
>>> from happy import *
>>> a, b
(1, 2)
```

Is there enough here for you to have a work-around?

Comment: Also, `globals_ = globals_ or globals()` is a bad idea.  What if someone intentionally passed an empty dict as `globals`?

Comment: @mgilson: Sure, I'll give you that. But this is in the scope of experimenting with `shelve` with calls to `globals`. As long as we are playing with explosives, I think this is a small concern. I'm sure OP knows what he is doing.