# Assigning index of a for to a variable noun

Tags: python

I have this variables:

```
time1 = end_time1 - start_time1
...
time2 = end_time2 - start_time2
...
time3 = end_time3 - start_time3
...
time4 = end_time4 - start_time4
...
time5 = end_time5 - start_time5
```

And I want to to this:

```
for i in range(5):
    print ("Search for " + str(i) + " element(s), has taken: " + "{0:.2f}".format(round(time,2)))
```

But, in `format(round(time,2))` I want to use index 'i' from for to name the variable time like time1, time2, time3...

Any clue?

Comment: I think you should use a proper data structure, eg a list or a dict

Comment: That's another option, better, for sure, haha, but anyway, I want to know how I can do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `locals()`:

```
for i in range(5):
    print ("Search for " + str(i) + " element(s), has taken: " + "{0:.2f}".format(round(locals()['time'+str(i+1)],2)))
```

Comment: Ok, this "worked". I mean, I used `globals()` but I got this same error: [Key Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857768/shelve-code-gives-keyerror). So I changed `globals()` to `locals()` and all went perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Zariweya, Well glad to have been of a bit of help (kinda)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the time variables in a list (and really it probably would be advantageous to have the timeX variables as a list in the first place instead of separate variables).

```
times = [time1, time2, time3, time4, time5]

for i in range(5):
    print ("Search for " + str(i) + " element(s), has taken: " + \
           "{0:.2f}".format(round(times[i],2)))
```

Comment: Thank you too for your answer. Also right way to do it.