# Saving functions using shelve

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use the shelve python module to save my session output and reload it later, but I have found that if I have defined functions then I get an error in the reloading stage. Is there a problem with the way I am doing it? I based my code on an answer at [How can I save all the variables in the current python session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-can-i-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session) .

Here's some simple code that reproduces the error:

```
def test_fn():  #simple test function
    return

import shelve
my_shelf = shelve.open('test_shelve','n')

for key in globals().keys():
    try:
        my_shelf[key] = globals()[key]
    except:  #__builtins__, my_shelf, and imported modules cannot be shelved.
        pass

my_shelf.close()
```

Then if I exit I can do

```
ls -lh test_shelve*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  22K Aug 24 11:16 test_shelve.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 476K Aug 24 11:16 test_shelve.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  22K Aug 24 11:16 test_shelve.dir
```

In general, in a new IPython session I want to be able to do something like:

```
import shelve
my_shelf = shelve.open('test_shelve')
for key in my_shelf:
    globals()[key]=my_shelf[key]
```

This produces an error for key 'test_fn'. Here is some code to demonstrate the error:

```
print my_shelf['test_fn']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-deb481380237> in <module>()
----> 1 print my_shelf['test_fn']

/home/user/anaconda2/envs/main/lib/python2.7/shelve.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    120         except KeyError:
    121             f = StringIO(self.dict[key])
--> 122             value = Unpickler(f).load()
    123             if self.writeback:
    124                 self.cache[key] = value

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_fn'
```

Of course, one solution would be to exclude functions in the saving stage, but from what I have read it should be possible to restore them with this method, and so I wondered if I am doing things wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `shelve` (or [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle), the actual protocol used by `shelve`) to store *executable code*, no.

What is stored is a *reference* to the function (just the location where the function can be imported from again). Code is not data, only the fact that you referenced a function is data here. Pickle expects to be able to load the same module and function again when you load the stored information.

The same would apply to classes; if you pickle a reference to a class, or pickle an instance of a class, then only the information to import the class again is stored (to re-create the reference or instance).

All this is done because you *already* have a persisted and loadable representation of that function or class: the module that defines them. There is no need to store another copy.

This is documented explicitly in the [*What can be pickled and unpickled?* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.

To go into some more detail for your specific example: The main script that Python executes is called the `__main__` module, and you shelved the `__main__.test_fn` function. What is stored then is simply a marker that signals you referenced a *global* and the import location, so something close to `GLOBAL` and `__main__` plus `test_fn` are stored. When loading the shelved data again, upon seeing the `GLOBAL` marker, the `pickle` module tries to load the name `test_fn` from the `__main__` module. Since your second script is again loaded as `__main__` but doesn't have a `test_fn` global, loading the reference fails.

Comment: OK thanks. Is testing whether the object I am trying to add to my_shelf is a function when saving, and only adding it if it is not, a good way to solve the problem? Are there other object types that could cause problems?

Comment: @user3798292: see the [`pickle` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) as to what can and can't be pickled. I've included that reference in my answer.

Comment: @user3798292: rather than try and shelve *everything* in your module, why not explicitly shelve anything that is actually of importance to your problem at hand? Explicit is better than implicit here.

Comment: True, though sometimes it is useful to be able to quickly save a whole session and reload it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a function in a shelf but you can store strings, so store the functions as a string then use exec() or eval() to use them from the shelve
To change a function to a string use inpect.getsource()
However , you cannot use inspect.getsource when directly running the interpreter

when storing a function:

```
#function
sq=lambda x:x*x
def sum(n,n2):
    return n+n2

#---------------
import shelve
from inspect import getsource
with shelve.open('path to shelf') as mem:
    sf=getsource(sum)
    mem['sum function']='def {}'+sf[sf.index('('):]
    mem['lambda function']=getsource(sq)
```

getsource() does not work if you are not running a file

when putting the function into your program:

```
import shelve
with shelve.open('path to shelf') as mem:
    previous_lambda=eval(mem['lambda function'])
    exec(mem['sum function'].format('prev_f'))#prev_f being the name of the function


#now you can use your functions
print(previous_lambda(4))
print(prev_f(2,3))
```

in case you need to know whether a function is a lambda or a normal function (because both of them are stored differently):

```
if func.__name__=="<lambda>":
    print('func is lambda')
elif callable(func):
    print('func is an ordinary function')
else:
    print('func is not a function')
```