# Can I drag and drop pickle files into PyCharm the same way I can d-n-d .mat files into Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, ide, pycharm, pickle

In Matlab, I can drag-and-drop a .mat key-value-pair data file into the Matlab window and it will populate the Workspace of variables.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Python world, namely drag-and-drop .pkl files into PyCharm?

I can see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-can-i-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session)  that I can use shelve rather than pickle for this goal.  Then any ideas on how to make this more drag-and-drop-y in context of PyCharm IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PyCharm** doesn't do that. Meantime, you can read a `.pkl` file by using code in a pretty simple way. The following approach uses `pickle` library.

### Example

```
import pickle

# read python dict back from the file
pkl_file = open('myfile.pkl', 'rb')
mydict2 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pkl_file.close()

print mydict2
```

#### Reference:

https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/saving-python-dict-to-file-using-pickle/

Comment: That gives me a dictionary called mydict2, how do I load the elements of that dictionary into the current environment, i.e. if mydict2={'a':12}, how do I get the same effect as typing a=12 into the interpreter?

Comment: Actually that is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-can-i-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session).

Comment: I will close this as answered because nobody is claiming that PyCharm can be fiddled with to get it to do drag and drop of [shelves](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) or pickles.  So I'll take that as a No, by default judgment.