# How to save image reading & code training result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, spyder

I am writing a program to differentiate between two types of plots (images) using features such as number of peaks. The reading of the image and training takes about 15 - 20 minutes.

Everytime I open spyder to modify the code I have to run the code again because all the variable are cleared  and wait.

Is there a way to save the images reading results, which comes out as a list,  and the training results so I do not have to wait?

**note: I am reading the images through[ cv2 ] & I am using spyder.**

Comment: Actually, the reverse should be true for Spyder. Depending on how you set this up, the image should be In a global namespace and accessible over multiple runs. As an aside, 20 minutes makes me think you might have some catastrophic runtime complexity. It's perfectly possible, but seems unlikely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save all the variables in the current python session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-can-i-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session)

Comment: the images are about 500 images and maybe the way my function is searching through those images in not efficient. @MohammadJavad is the result of training the the data with a classifier is considered a variable?