# Is there an equivalent of R's save.image() function in Python?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

When working in R, one has the ability to save the entire "workspace", variables, output, etc... to an image file using "save.image()". Is there something equivalent in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save all the variables in the current python session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-can-i-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `r`, but `pickle` offers functionality to save and load `(variables, objects, types, etc...)` in a `pickle` file. In this way you can save any details needed for a later session. I'm unsure if `pickle` offers a specific way to save all data associated with the current session or if you would be required to manually locate and save. Hope this helps!

```
import pickle 
my_obj = Object()
my_var = (1,"some_data")
filename = "my_dir\my_file.pickle"
with open(filename, ‘wb’) as f: #save data
    pickle.dump((my_obj, my_var), f)

with open(filename, ‘rb’) as f: #load data next time
    my_saved_obj, my_saved_var = pickle.load(f)
```