# Save all python variables in file via shelve module raising KeyError

Tags: python, save

I followed this topic [How to save all the variables in the current python session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-to-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session) to save all my python variables in a file.

I did the following code:

```
import shelve

def saveWorkspaceVariables(pathSavedVariables):
    # This functions saves all the variables in a file.
    my_shelf = shelve.open(pathSavedVariables,'n') # 'n' for new
    
    for key in dir():
        try:
            my_shelf[key] = globals()[key]
        except TypeError:
            #
            # __builtins__, my_shelf, and imported modules can not be shelved.
            #
            print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(key))
    my_shelf.close()
    
T="test"

saveWorkspaceVariables("file.out")
```

However, it raises: `KeyError: 'my_shelf'`.

Why so? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you step through the code line-by-line with a debugger to see what `key` is when there's an error?

Comment: `dir()` includes local variables, but `globals()` doesn't.

Comment: Use `for key in globals()`

Answer (score 0):

May not be the answer you're looking for, but depending on what IDE you're using you may be able to save your session from there. I know Spyder has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `dir()` function without an argument returns a list of all the names in the current scope. This list includes the function's local variables, such as `my_shelf` and `pathSavedVariables`.

But since these are local variables, `globals()` won't include them, since it only returns global variables.

You don't need to save the local variables, so you shouldn't use `dir()`. Use `globals()` to get all the global variables.

```
for key in globals():
```

The reason it works in the other question is that the code is not in a function, so there are no local variables to exclude.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if I switch from dir() to globals() in the for, I get an error: "Can't pickle <built-in function input>: it's not the same object as builtins.input"

Comment: Some data types, such as functions, can't be serialized. You probably should only save your application variables, not all the built-in variables.

Comment: So in the end what I want is really that the variable that I made during my script (not the functions, only the variables) are saved into a file. I have many of them so I cannot do it "one by one". How can I proceed ?

Comment: See the comments in the original question. Change `except TypeError:` to a more general `except:`

Comment: You should make a list of those variables, and loop through that instead of using `globals()`.