# Is it possible to add a new key to a dictionary in Python then save the key into the file for later use?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to add a key to a dictionary with the update() method, but since the program might need to be closed, I need for the key to be saved backed into the file for later use.

If I add the key `{'car' : 'purple'}` to the dictionary it would save as:

```
dict = {
        {'truck' : 'blue'},
        {'mini' : 'green'},
        {'car' : 'purple'}

}
```

instead of in its previous value.

```
dict = {
        {'truck' : 'blue'},
        {'mini' : 'green'}

}
```

Comment: Is this meant to be a list of dicts?

Comment: Do you want to save the whole dictionary to a file? Or just the added key (in this case 'car') or the added item ('car', 'purple')

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a value to a variable, for example the `dict` type you show, it is not saved in any file. If you want to persist the variable to a file you will need to do something special.

If you work in the Python shell (aka REPL) you can use [shelve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961077/553865) to persist the name/value pairs.

If you want your own program to save data, that data could be written to a JSON file, or saved in a database.

BTW, it is considered bad practice to name a variable `dict` because that is also a type.

Also, your use of the term `default state` would be better expressed as `previous value`, because you have not indicated that this variable is assigned from a property in an API or framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file simply to a text file and import it when need be.

```
dict = {'truck': 'blue', 'mini': 'green', 'car': 'purple'}
  

new_file = open('newfile.txt', 'wt')
new_file.write(str(dict))
new_file.close()
```