# How to save the state of a ipynb file in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, save

I want to save the state of the ipynb file in vscode. Not only the results, but the actual state (memory) with all the processing made.

If we have a heavy processing to do, it's time consuming if we need to close the vscode and then rerun the whole ipynb.

Tried to search on internet, but did not find anything specific.

Comment: You can try using [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) to save Python objects, or you can try using a remote server to run files on the server, which will be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try exporting `globals()` and `locals()` and loading them back in, as suggested in [other stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-to-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session).