# framework for suspending/hibernating whole applications

Tags: operating-system, suspend

The highlevel problem is: suspending/hibernating entire user level applications is hard due to difficulties in restoring state related to opened files, sockets, etc. 
Now, are there any environments who are addressing this issue ? ex. combination of OS techniques combined with restriction on the applications, etc. Is there any OS that implements such a thing, except the classical virtual machine suspend ?

Any thoughts or resources appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Found another helpful thread : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134771/hibernate-a-process-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

[BLCR](https://ftg.lbl.gov/CheckpointRestart/CheckpointRestart.shtml) does this on Linux systems with a kernel module to help some of the low level detail bits.