# How can I save the state of running python programs to resume later?

Tags: python, linux

I am developing the machine learning analysis program which has to process the 27GB of text files in linux. Although my production system won't be rebooted very often but I need to test that in my home computer or development environment.

Now I have power failure very often so I can hardly run it continuously for 3 weeks.

My programs reads the files, applies some parsing, saves the filtered data in new files in dictionary, then I apply the algorithm on those files then saves result in mysqlDB.

I am not able to find how can I save the algorithm state.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5697720/946850, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2134771/946850. Bottom line of the answers: Don't try saving the state of the entire process, but save "user data" (as suggested by tripplet). See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I everything regarding the algorithm state is saved in a class, you can serialize the class an save it to disk: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: ...or cPickle to make it faster

Answer (score 1):

Since the entire algorithm state can be saved in a class, you might want to use `pickle` (as mentioned above), [but `pickle` comes with it's own overloads and risks](http://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/).

For better ways to do the same, you might want to check out [this article](https://eev.ee/blog/2015/10/15/dont-use-pickle-use-camel/), which explains why you should use the `camel` library instead of `pickle`.